# Is it possible to perform a Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest from a content script in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

The documentation for [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) makes it seem like I should be able to access a http resource from a page loaded over https as long as I use the correct permissions. Yet I get the following error message when attempting this.

```
content.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.example.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.example.com/*",
    "https://www.example.com/*",
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://www.example.com/*",
        "https://www.example.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

content.js:

```
fetch('http://www.example.com/').then(response => {
    console.log('Done!')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't CORS. It's mixed content, and you can't workaround even in extension.

You can move your request to backround page (by message passing).

Comment: Alternatively, if you own 'example.com' consider hosting the endpoint on https instead. If you don't own it you could proxy it through your own https server.